# CS0246 and CS0433 errors when building .NET 4.0 website on Server 2012

Tags: .net, teamcity-7.0, psake

I am building a .Net 4.0 web project on Server 2012 with .Net 4.5 installed.  I am using Psake under TeamCity and am getting CS0246 saying NotMapped could not be found, along with CS0433 saying it has found two DLLs for DataAnnotations.

The class looks like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
public abstract class Order
{
   [NotMapped]
   public decimal TaxPercentage { get; set; }
}
```

The full errors are:

```
Ordering\Order.cs(105,8): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NotMapped' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\71c853cb9b4c108\Code\Models\Model.csproj]
Ordering\Order.cs(105,8): error CS0433: The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMappedAttribute' exists in both 'c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\71c853cb9b4c108\Code\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll' [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\71c853cb9b4c108\Code\Models\Model.csproj]
```

The build works fine under Windows 8 using just Psake and not TeamCity.  Any ideas how to resolve this?

Update: I've made a smaller test [project](https://bitbucket.org/seankearon/ef-build-test) and this builds fine on 2012.  Looks like there's something weird with my main project.

Comment: Could you check your local version of the EF and the remote TC version?

Comment: Both are 4.4.20627.0.

Comment: About the GAC is EF installed in your local machine?

Comment: No, EF is not in the GAC on my local machine.

Comment: So if you register the EF in your local machine you will be able to reproduce the error in the TC environment. It is a conflict between the same class in two namespaces.

Comment: Afraid not - it still compiles fine locally with EF in the GAC.  It appears that the namespaces are the same, but it appears in two separate DLLs.

Comment: I just made test program and everything is working. What about if you remove the EF from the GAC and enable the project to download the packages using NuGet?

Comment: gustavodidomenico - sorry, didn't see your comment before I updated.  I have just done the same.  Looks like there is something odd with my main project.  Will try what you say and get back...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` shipped in EF 4.4, whereas they are in a separate assembly for EF 5.0.  I had a mix of EF references in my projects which I have now rebuilt - all to use EF 5 and it's fixed the problem.